# Copy to clipboard with Vaadin button in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, vaadin, clipboard

Here is the code for the Vaadin button:

```
String textToCopy = "COPY ME!!!";
Button copyBtn = new Button("");
copyBtn.setButtonLayout(false, new IconSelf(VaadinIcon.COPY_O), "Copy"));
copyBtn.addClickListener(event -> {
          getUI().get().getPage().executeJs("navigator.clipboard.writeText(`" + textToCopy + "`);");
    Notification.show(getTranslation(PAGESTRING + "attributestoclipboard"))
});
```

To copy my custom text I used `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)`.
Works in *Chrome* and *Edge* but **not** in *Firefox*.
Firefox also blocked `document.execCommand("copy")` when i used it in the `executeJS(...)` function.

I think i need to add a `onClick` function to the button. How can i do this with Vaadin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
copyBtn.getElement().executeJs("this.addEventListener('click', e => navigator.clipboard.writeText($0))", textToCopy);
```

Note that it's strongly discouraged to use string concatenation to dynamically build strings that are passed to `executeJs` because of the risk of cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. That's why my suggestion also uses `$0` to reference the separately passed string. This is similar to using prepared statements with SQL.